# Is it possible to use a @argfile for the classpath generation within install4j?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to use a @argfile for the classpath generation within install4j?
I haven't found anything in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

install4j will not use argument files for the classpath that you can configure in the launcher wizard, because it does not pass the classpath on the command line.

However, the `@argfile` syntax is supported by install4j and you can use it in the VM parameters field.